# White space between my bootstrap navbar and carousel below

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my site http://www.noor-azmi.com/element/index.html

There is a white space between the navbar and the carousel below

I already tried the

```
.navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

but it does not work. It only worked when i changed the carousel to a normal img image.

```
<div class="banner" img src="....">
```

pls help thanks

2nd issuei am also facing with my site is when in firefox, when i click to another page "Home" "Company" & "Contact", the browser will auto scroll down and will show the page below the navbar.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.fullslider` class you have `margin-top: 40px;`

It'll look like you want it once you remove it.

Comment: Thanks, i did not notice it. Cause i have 2 .fullslider in my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following css to your style file it will fix your issue

```
.fullslider {
    margin-top: 0px !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks i solved the first issue.

How about the 2nd one. The weird scrolling in firefox, the website will automatically scroll below the nav